# How to find positions of $n$ masses in Newton mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, many-body, non-linear-systems

I ran into a problem while doing research. The problem can be described as: consider the original $n$-body problem, and if we fix the position of them(unknowns), no interaction among them, they don't ever move at all. I want to find out their positions.   Now I put a test point with a small mass somewhere (known to me) in the system. I can measure the force it receives, I can write down one equation : 
$$
\sum_{j=1,...,n}\frac{G m_{0}m_j\mathbf{r}_{0j}}{||r_{0j}||^3} = \mathbf{F}_{0},
$$
where $G$ is a constant, $m_0, m_j$ are known to me, $\mathbf{r}_{0j} = \mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{x}_0$ is the distance vector. $\mathbf{F}_{0}$ can be measured. $\mathbf{x}_0$ is the position of the test point, and $\mathbf{x}_j$ is the location of the $j^{\rm th}$ object.

if I move the test point $0$ to many other places, I can get many equations (as many as I want). My question is: how can I solve the positions of the bodies $x_j$ from these equations? 
Numerical solution is enough for me, I mainly use python programming language, any suggestion on how to solve this non-linear equation system?

Comment: You might be interested in NumPy and SciPy libraries. Also do consider looking at "Monte-Carlo" simulation of n-body systems.

Comment: This is cross-posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/631560/  I think it is better at math than here

Comment: If you would take the gradient of the force (potential) as a function of position and make a contour plot out of it you should de able to determine the location of the stationary bodies.

Comment: Depending on the value of $n$, you are likely going to have to move away from interpreted languages and invest time learning C or Fortran.

Comment: @RossMillikan , sorry, I am quite new here, wasn't sure where to post. My problem is a physics problem, but it calls for techniques solving non-linear equations. Should I delete the post here?

Comment: @fibonatic  yes, you're right, but that requires many runs of the program, I'd like to solve for the positions under the model I proposed and achieve this with the least amount runs of program as possible. Thanks

Comment: @KyleKanos , Yes, if the problem is too expensive, I will write a C functions. Thanks

Comment: Would http://scicomp.stackexchange.com be a better home for this question?

Comment: I actually think this question fits best here, though of course answers here would focus on the physics (i.e. how many points one needs and how to choose them), not the details of the numerical computation. (If the question was meant to be about the numerics, then yes, it should go to [scicomp.SE].) Regardless, it shouldn't be posted both here and on math. johnniac, I guess it's your choice but you should probably delete one or the other.

Comment: Is there anything else known about the system? For instance is there an a priori 'bounding box' for mass positions? What about the distributions of masses $m_j$? I suspect that there would be considerable difference in the search between cases of nearly similar masses and the case where some of the masses differ by orders of magnitude from the rest.

Comment: @user23660 , Yes, there is a bounding box. I am trying to find the locations of the stationary mass points, assuming same magnitude. I can use the test point as many times as I want. Any suggestions on the problem? Or any similar ones?

Comment: @johnniac: I am thinking that there should exist something  like 'inverse' fast multipole method for this problem. (For introduction to FMM, see links at http://fastmultipole.org/Main/Tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a method, although it may require to compute $\mathbf{F}_0$ for a very large number of test points. It is based on [Gauss's law for gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity)
$$ \frac1{m_0}\oint_{S} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S=-4\pi GM_S$$
where $S$ is a closed surface and $M_S$ is the total mass contained inside it.

So the idea would be to use some numerical scheme to compute the total mass contained inside some cubes, explore space and identify the regions where there is mass and where there is nothing. I suggest to start with large cubes and look for one that contains all the mass $\sum_jm_j$. Once you have delimited it, divide the size by two, this divides your cube into eight smaller ones, look in which you have mass and iterate until you have isolated masses correspoding to your $m_j$. This algorithm ends, but may be quite time consuming...

Comment: Thanks for your input, however, I only can measure the force on the test mass combined from all the unknown masses. I don't have the control to turn down a subset of masses.

Comment: @johnniac. Using the formula I wrote, you don't need to turn down any mass. Only the mass inside the cube contributes to the integral. The masses outside the cube, whatever their positions, do not contribute ! Try it on with an example !

Comment: @johnniac. More specifically: Rewrite formula (1) as $-(1/4\pi Gm_0)\oint_S\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S=M_S$. You have on the left-hand hide something you can compute from the values of $\mathbf F$ at the points of the surface of the cube. The right-hand is the sum of the masses contained inside the cube. The masses that are outside of the cube *do not contribute*, so you don't need to turn them down, it's done by the formula.